# IOS Access Push notification payload before user gets push notif

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to access the push notification payload before user actually gets the push notification. I want to create some sort of filter of the push notifications that the user receives. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you trying to achieve through filter. Do u want to show selected type of notification in navigation bar and not all or something else??

Comment: you need to filter the tokens for pushes _before_ you sent it – on your server side; on the device you can post-process only _after_ it was delivered.

Answer (score 3):

You can get notification payload before it fired using this extension "NotificationService"

Add one target in the project and you can get notification data in bellow function.

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {

}
```

One more thing you need to add is in notification payload add two-parameter like this

```
{
    "aps":{
       "alert": {
         "title": "This it title",
          "body": "This is body"
        },
        "mutable-content":1,
        "content-available":1
    },
    "mediaType": "png",
    "mediaUrl": "your url her"
}

"mutable-content":1,
"content-available":1
```

mutable content and content available = 1

if you do not add these two keys in payload then the above function should not call.

Thank you.

[image]